# How can I configure the network on my Kubuntu box to be a system connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, kubuntu

I would love to know how to configure Kubuntu to not use the NetworkManager so that I can go back to the old way of configuring a static IP in /etc/network/interfaces.
Can anyone help me with this?

I find the userspace plasma widget for configuring the network completely useless. I don't want to have to log into KDE in order for the network to come up, I just want a system wide, wired connection.

Can anyone help with a little advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove Network Manager altogether:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manag*
```

Then do:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Below the `loopback` stanza, add something like:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.108
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wireless-essid myrouter
wireless-key 0123456789
```

Substitute your details and use an IP address outside the range assigned by the DHCP server in the router. Proofread carefully, save and close gedit.

For WPA encryption, it's:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.108
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-essid myrouter
wpa-psk mysecretkey
```

Reboot and enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you don't have to replace NetworkManager.
It is not difficult to config NetworkManger to deploy static ip.

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
$ sudo vi <you ethernet connection name>

...
[ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=50:9A:4C:0B:96:0A
mac-address-blacklist=
speed=1000

[ipv4]
address1=10.1.0.211/24,10.1.0.216
dns=10.1.0.216;
dns-search=
may-fail=false
method=manual
...

$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Done